# live Sass Compile

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, scss, ftp, sftp

live Sass Compile как можно работать на сервере по FTP/SFTP

чтобы конвертация сразу работало

например:
сделаем проект на локальном, далее нужно публиковать сайт на хостинге, клиент хочет что-то изменить, вот как сделать все это максимально автоматизировано?

пробовал через плагин SFTP, но css файлы не создаётся...

Comment: используйте gulp

Comment: с gulp пока еще не знаком.. как я понял, с помощью этих плагинов не получится работать по FTP или можно?